# Json and Jackson stackoverflow loop with unidirectional relationships

Tags: java, json, spring, loops, jackson

I know that since Jackson 1.6 I can use two annotations to solve the infinite recursion problem: `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference`.

The problem is that these annotations seem to work only in bi-directional relationships. My loop, instead, grows between 4 objects bounded with uni-directional associations. I paste the attributes that cause the stackoverflow loop with Json.

**Cart:**

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
@JoinColumn(name = "cart_fk")
private Collection<CartLine> cartLines = new ArrayList<CartLine>();
```

**CartLine:**

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="product_fk")
private Product product;
```

**Product:**

```
@ManyToOne
private User user;
```

**User:**

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_fk")
private Collection<Cart> cart = new ArrayList<Cart>();
```

So I've got this loop: `Cart` -> `CartLine` -> `Product` -> `User` -> `Cart` -> and so on.

How can I stop this loop, created by unidirectional relationships?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can annotate your Entity with

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class)
```

using whichever Generator you want. This will give an identifier to each object. If that object comes up again, Jackson will use its id instead of serializing it fully.